# How to build a static library with libtensorflow-core.a and how to use it?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, build, static-libraries

I'm running my code on the `Ubuntu 16` system with `TensorFlow-1.13.0-rc2`.

First, I ran `bazel build //tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so` for generate some *.pb.h header files.
then run `./tensorflow/contrib/makefile/build_all_linux.sh` then get this files:
- `tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/libtensorflow-core.a`
- `tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/protobuf/lib/libprotobuf.a`
- `tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/nsync/builds/default.linux.c++11/libnsync.a`

then, the header is below:

// RecogLetter.h

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include "tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.pb.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/lib/strings/str_util.h"
#include "tensorflow/cc/ops/standard_ops.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/platform/default/logging.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/public/session.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/platform/types.h"

// using tensorflow::string;
using tensorflow::Status;
using tensorflow::Tensor;
using tensorflow::int32;
class RecogLetter
{
    public:
    RecogLetter();
    ~RecogLetter();

    public:
    int init(const std::string &model_path, const char* txtmap_path);
    int recog(cv::Mat *cv_image, char* label_index, float* score);

    private:
    int init_dictionary(const std::string& filename);

    Status LoadGraph(std::string graph_file_name,
                 std::unique_ptr<tensorflow::Session>* session);
    Status GetTopLabels(const std::vector<Tensor>& outputs, int how_many_labels,
                    Tensor* out_indices, Tensor* out_scores) ;
    Status PrintTopLabels(const std::vector<Tensor>& outputs, 
                    std::string labels_file_name, char* label_index, float* score); 
    Status CheckTopLabel(const std::vector<Tensor>& outputs, int expected,
                     bool* is_expected);

    private:
    std::unique_ptr<tensorflow::Session> session;
    std::string labels =  "";

    int32 _how_many_labels = 26;
    int32 input_channel = 1;
    int32 input_width = 32;
    int32 input_height = 32;
    int32 input_mean = 0;
    int32 input_std = 255;
    std::string input_layer = "input_node";
    std::string output_layer = "output_node";
    bool self_test = false;
    std::string root_dir = "";

    std::unordered_map<int, char> mapping;
};
```

and RecogLetter.cc is the implementation is this https://github.com/jesen8/recog_letter include all of the code.

and the CMakeLists.txt is below

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")

set(tensoflow_source_dir /home/swls/work_dir/github/tensorflow-1.13.0-rc2)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)


include_directories(
    ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${tensoflow_source_dir}
    ${tensoflow_source_dir}/bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles
    ${tensoflow_source_dir}/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/proto
    ${tensoflow_source_dir}/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/proto_text
    ${tensoflow_source_dir}/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/host_obj
    ${tensoflow_source_dir}/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/protobuf/include
    ${tensoflow_source_dir}/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/eigen
    ${tensoflow_source_dir}/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/nsync/public
    ${tensoflow_source_dir}/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/absl
    ${tensoflow_source_dir}/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/googletest/googletest/include
    )
    # ${tensoflow_source_dir}/include)

link_directories(
    ${OpenCV_LIBRARY_DIRS}
    # /usr/local/lib
    # ${tensoflow_source_dir}/bazel-bin/tensorflow
    # ${tensoflow_source_dir}/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/nsync/builds/default.linux.c++11
    # ${tensoflow_source_dir}/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib
    # ${tensoflow_source_dir}/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/protobuf/lib
    )


SET(param "-std=c++11 -Wall -L${tensoflow_source_dir}/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/protobuf-host/lib -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition -Wl,--whole-archive  ${tensoflow_source_dir}/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/libtensorflow-core.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive ${tensoflow_source_dir}/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/nsync/builds/default.linux.c++11/nsync.a -lstdc++ -l:libprotobuf.a -lz -lm -ldl -lpthread -lrt")

set(SIMPLE_MODEL "recog_letter")

add_library(${SIMPLE_MODEL} STATIC RecogLetter.cc RecogLetter.h)


target_link_libraries(${SIMPLE_MODEL} ${OpenCV_LIBS})

target_link_libraries(${SIMPLE_MODEL} ${param})
```

and can build successfully,then got the librecog_letter.a

```
total 540
drwxrwxr-x 3 swls swls   4096 5月  22 11:13 ./
drwxrwxr-x 5 swls swls   4096 5月  22 11:10 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 swls swls  13272 5月  22 11:12 CMakeCache.txt
drwxrwxr-x 5 swls swls   4096 5月  22 11:13 CMakeFiles/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 swls swls   1477 5月  22 11:10 cmake_install.cmake
-rw-rw-r-- 1 swls swls 511870 5月  22 11:13 librecog_letter.a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 swls swls   5222 5月  22 11:13 Makefile
```

and last i will use the librecog_letter.a.

the code is very little

```
#include "RecogLetter.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  RecogLetter recog_letter;

  int ret_code = recog_letter.init(argv[1], argv[2]);

  return ret_code;
}
```

i also can build successfully.

```
drwxrwxr-x 3 swls swls      4096 5月  22 11:28 ./
drwxrwxr-x 3 swls swls      4096 5月  22 11:20 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 swls swls     12123 5月  22 11:20 CMakeCache.txt
drwxrwxr-x 5 swls swls      4096 5月  22 11:28 CMakeFiles/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 swls swls      1487 5月  22 11:20 cmake_install.cmake
-rw-rw-r-- 1 swls swls      5175 5月  22 11:28 Makefile
-rwxrwxr-x 1 swls swls 158587704 5月  22 11:28 recog_letter_test*



is there anyone can help me? thanks so much.

there is some info for help my build
[https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28388#issuecomment-490670167](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28388#issuecomment-490670167)
```

but when i run `./recog_letter_test **.output.pb  **.label`, the error is below:

```
2019-05-22 11:29:48.447661: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1325] OpKernel ('op: "StatelessMultinomial" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "T" allowed_values { list { type: DT_DOUBLE } } } constraint { name: "output_dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_INT64 } } }') for unknown op: StatelessMultinomial
2019-05-22 11:29:48.447896: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1325] OpKernel ('op: "StatelessMultinomial" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "T" allowed_values { list { type: DT_DOUBLE } } } constraint { name: "output_dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_INT32 } } }') for unknown op: StatelessMultinomial
2019-05-22 11:29:48.447906: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1325] OpKernel ('op: "StatelessMultinomial" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "T" allowed_values { list { type: DT_FLOAT } } } constraint { name: "output_dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_INT64 } } }') for unknown op: StatelessMultinomial
2019-05-22 11:29:48.447912: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1325] OpKernel ('op: "StatelessMultinomial" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "T" allowed_values { list { type: DT_FLOAT } } } constraint { name: "output_dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_INT32 } } }') for unknown op: StatelessMultinomial
2019-05-22 11:29:48.447918: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1325] OpKernel ('op: "StatelessMultinomial" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "T" allowed_values { list { type: DT_HALF } } } constraint { name: "output_dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_INT64 } } }') for unknown op: StatelessMultinomial
2019-05-22 11:29:48.447945: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1325] OpKernel ('op: "StatelessMultinomial" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "T" allowed_values { list { type: DT_HALF } } } constraint { name: "output_dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_INT32 } } }') for unknown op: StatelessMultinomial
2019-05-22 11:29:48.447983: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1325] OpKernel ('op: "LookupTableFindV2" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: LookupTableFindV2
2019-05-22 11:29:48.448003: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1325] OpKernel ('op: "MutableHashTable" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "key_dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_STRING } } } constraint { name: "value_dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_INT64 } } }') for unknown op: MutableHashTable
2019-05-22 11:29:48.448010: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1325] OpKernel ('op: "MutableHashTable" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "key_dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_STRING } } } constraint { name: "value_dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_INT32 } } }') for unknown op: MutableHashTable
2019-05-22 11:29:48.448016: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1325] OpKernel ('op: "MutableHashTable" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "key_dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_STRING } } } constraint { name: "value_dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_FLOAT } } }') for unknown op: MutableHashTable
2019-05-22 11:29:48.448022: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1325] OpKernel ('op: "MutableHashTable" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "key_dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_STRING } } } constraint { name: "value_dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_DOUBLE } } }') for unknown op: MutableHashTable
2019-05-22 11:29:48.448031: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1325] OpKernel ('op: "MutableHashTable" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "key_dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_STRING } } } constraint { name: "value_dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_BOOL } } }') for unknown op: MutableHashTable
2019-05-22 11:29:48.448041: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1325] OpKernel ('op: "MutableHashTable" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "key_dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_INT64 } } } constraint { name: "value_dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_VARIANT } } }') for unknown op: MutableHashTable

...
...
2019-05-22 11:29:48.460537: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1325] OpKernel ('op: "HashTable" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "key_dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_INT32 } } } constraint { name: "value_dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_INT32 } } }') for unknown op: HashTable
2019-05-22 11:29:48.460547: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1325] OpKernel ('op: "HashTable" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "key_dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_INT32 } } } constraint { name: "value_dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_FLOAT } } }') for unknown op: HashTable
2019-05-22 11:29:48.460557: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1325] OpKernel ('op: "HashTable" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "key_dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_INT32 } } } constraint { name: "value_dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_DOUBLE } } }') for unknown op: HashTable
2019-05-22 11:29:48.460831: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1325] OpKernel ('op: "StatelessRandomUniform" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_DOUBLE } } } host_memory_arg: "shape" host_memory_arg: "seed"') for unknown op: StatelessRandomUniform
2019-05-22 11:29:48.460841: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1325] OpKernel ('op: "StatelessRandomUniform" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_FLOAT } } } host_memory_arg: "shape" host_memory_arg: "seed"') for unknown op: StatelessRandomUniform
2019-05-22 11:29:48.460850: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1325] OpKernel ('op: "StatelessRandomUniform" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_BFLOAT16 } } } host_memory_arg: "shape" host_memory_arg: "seed"') for unknown op: StatelessRandomUniform
2019-05-22 11:29:48.460860: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1325] OpKernel ('op: "StatelessRandomUniform" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_HALF } } } host_memory_arg: "shape" host_memory_arg: "seed"') for unknown op: StatelessRandomUniform
2019-05-22 11:29:48.460870: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1325] OpKernel ('op: "StatelessRandomNormal" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_DOUBLE } } } host_memory_arg: "shape" host_memory_arg: "seed"') for unknown op: StatelessRandomNormal
2019-05-22 11:29:48.460880: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1325] OpKernel ('op: "StatelessRandomNormal" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_FLOAT } } } host_memory_arg: "shape" host_memory_arg: "seed"') for unknown op: StatelessRandomNormal
2019-05-22 11:29:48.460890: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1325] OpKernel ('op: "StatelessRandomNormal" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_BFLOAT16 } } } host_memory_arg: "shape" host_memory_arg: "seed"') for unknown op: StatelessRandomNormal
2019-05-22 11:29:48.460900: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1325] OpKernel ('op: "StatelessRandomNormal" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_HALF } } } host_memory_arg: "shape" host_memory_arg: "seed"') for unknown op: StatelessRandomNormal
2019-05-22 11:29:48.460909: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1325] OpKernel ('op: "StatelessTruncatedNormal" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_DOUBLE } } } host_memory_arg: "shape" host_memory_arg: "seed"') for unknown op: StatelessTruncatedNormal
2019-05-22 11:29:48.460919: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1325] OpKernel ('op: "StatelessTruncatedNormal" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_FLOAT } } } host_memory_arg: "shape" host_memory_arg: "seed"') for unknown op: StatelessTruncatedNormal
2019-05-22 11:29:48.460929: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1325] OpKernel ('op: "StatelessTruncatedNormal" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_BFLOAT16 } } } host_memory_arg: "shape" host_memory_arg: "seed"') for unknown op: StatelessTruncatedNormal
2019-05-22 11:29:48.460939: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1325] OpKernel ('op: "StatelessTruncatedNormal" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_HALF } } } host_memory_arg: "shape" host_memory_arg: "seed"') for unknown op: StatelessTruncatedNormal
2019-05-22 11:29:48.460950: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1325] OpKernel ('op: "StatelessRandomUniformInt" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_INT64 } } } host_memory_arg: "shape" host_memory_arg: "seed" host_memory_arg: "minval" host_memory_arg: "maxval"') for unknown op: StatelessRandomUniformInt
2019-05-22 11:29:48.460961: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1325] OpKernel ('op: "StatelessRandomUniformInt" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "dtype" allowed_values { list { type: DT_INT32 } } } host_memory_arg: "shape" host_memory_arg: "seed" host_memory_arg: "minval" host_memory_arg: "maxval"') for unknown op: StatelessRandomUniformInt
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with one of my models derived from Materport RCNN

I get the following error

ERROR: Op type not registered 'DenseToDenseSetOperation' in binary running on creative2. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.

Creative2 is the clients machine name

Having a quick GitHub search it seems this op is a thing

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9590c4c32dd4346ea5c35673336f5912c6072bf2/tensorflow/core/ops/set_ops.cc

So given that it is there in core I don’t know what to do to make sure it is initialised it is in the dynamic version of the same software

Sam

Answer (score 0):

Answer is found here:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28942#issuecomment-494989399

see the docs

The most common cause of breakages are files that have been added to the Bazel build scripts, but that the makefile isn't aware of. Typical symptoms of this include linker errors mentioning missing symbols or protobuf headers that aren't found. To address these problems, take a look at the *.txt files in tensorflow/contrib/makefile. If you have a new operator, you may need to add it to tf_op_files.txt, or for a new proto to tf_proto_files.txt.

You can find which .cc file has your operator and add it to the appropriate text file.